# OpenCV on a Mac

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, opencv

First off I'm new to the site and also fairly young in the programming world so some of my terminology may be a little off but hopefully you all can get the point.

I'm trying to setup OpenCV in eclipse (using java)and am having some issues. I'm trying to follow the tutorials on the OpenCV website found here http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/java_eclipse/java_eclipse.html#java-eclipse

I've downloaded OpenCV and extracted it, but when I try to create my own library in eclipse, there is no "Build" file (or any .jar file) to be found included in the download. I've also tried downloading older versions of OpenCV thinking they would be different but I can't find the .jar file in any of them either.

I've also tried looking through some of previous forums on here discussing the issue (at least on the java side of things) and most of them all have the same steps as the OpenCV tutorial has, I just can't seem to find the folder needed to link the library.

The end goal is I'm trying access the webcam in one of the Java projects I'm working on.

Comment: you will have to *build* the opencv libs using cmake first. this will *generate* the java bindings as well.

Comment: see [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/desktop_java/java_dev_intro.html#build) (for a very collapsed version)

Comment: FYI, it's pretty easy to use the precompiled version of OpenCV that comes with JavaCPP: https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/tree/master/opencv

Answer (score -1):

I've been stuck with installing openCV on Mac for a while :) There are no really good guides how to do it (beside one or two) so I'll post my tutorial here:

1. First of all You need to download openCV from SourceForge. I dont recommend the latest version, it's better to use one version behind (like 2.4.9 not 2.4.10).

[image]

2. Download javaCV (latest version).

[image]

3. Download Cmake.

[image]

4. Put all openCV and javaCV in any direction You will remember.
5. Install and run Cmake.
6. From Cmake interface select openCV folder (look two steps earlier) as a Source Direction. Make a new Folder for a Build Direction and name it as You want (for example "*mybuildedOpenCV*").
7. Click CONFIGURE. Wait till Cmake end his job. There will be many red colors, so dont get a heart attack :)
8. Click Generate. Wait till Cmake finishes. Check Your *mybuildedOpenCV* folder. There should be new items!
9. Now the harder part. You can make a cigarette break now. Done? Ok. So go to Your Terminal app. Open it. Then go to Your *mybuildedOpenCV* folder and drag&drop it to the terminal. You should find a path by it. Use a command: **cd /your/path/*mybuildedOpenCV***.
10. If You succed entering your build folder write in Terminal: **make**. Just "make", nothing else. Press Enter. Now Your *mybuildedOpenCV* should start to build itself :) You must get to 100% without any error. If there is and error and build stops earlier, check if everything is alright and start again.
11. If You succed, check your *mybuildedOpenCV* folder. There should be new folders in it, "bin" etc.
12. Find a "lib" folder. Select all files in it and copy them. You must paste them to Your usr/lib or usr/local/lib directory. To enter this directory open Finder and select "Go" and then "To the catalogue". Type there "/usr". If there is a local folder , enter it. If not, enter "lib". Paste everything in there.
13. Now get back to Your orignal openCV folder, the one that You had downloaded. In there You must find "include" folder. Copy opencv and opencv2 from there and paste them to /usr/include or /usr/local/include.
14. Now the tricky part. Go again to Your original openCV folder. Enter "modules" folder. You must copy&paste folders from there to the /usr/include/opencv2 or usr/local/include/opencv2 to make it look like mine opencv2 folder:

[image]

It is done.

Comment: BTW, the latest version of JavaCV is on GitHub now: https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv